# Raspbian Buster Video Player Display

Tags: video, berryboot, raspbian-buster

I installed Rasppian buster on pi 3 on my 8GB SDCard, No issue what so ever playing video on Chrome, VLC, etc. I now did a squashfs file to boot Raspbian Buster via Berryboot where I have more storage space of 256GB.

Everything is ok except I can't play video files. VLC hangs when press play. Chrome browser plays sound but displays like this on YouTube.
[image]

Any fix for this?

No Problem with Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow got it fixed. I installed smplayer, xine and gstreamer-plugins and all is back to normal.
[image]

Seems some plugins were missing which I am not sure the exact one. Please more answers needed to be sure what caused it. I am interested to know.

Comment: I had a [similar problem](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=238411) after Chromium updated. Solved it by setting GPU memory to 80 MB.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.